# JavaScript: represent float as product of integer and power of ten

Tags: javascript, fixed-point

For instance, I have float 1.1111111111 and need to get 11111111111 and 10.

I want to avoid functions, which may change part after point as I need it to show metric prefixes.

It may look simple with strings, I am just not sure if it is a proper way in JavaScript.

Comment: Did you try something ? What was the problem ? To get the index of the dot you may use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: I did part of it in another way:
    var x = 1.1111111111;
    y=(x.toString().replace(".", ""));
    y/x;

Comment: So what are you looking for ?

Comment: I thought, that conversion seem a little odd, so I am just interested if there's a way to get power of ten without strings.

Comment: You could loop and multiply your second factor by 10 at each iteration but that will be verbose and not so faster. In fact you can write this in so many ways, only benchmarks would give the best solution (you can use http://jsperf.com/). I doubt there is a very simple and fast solution.

Comment: @dystroy http://jsperf.com/scinot - I compared my solution with ISE's from above. Looks like they're almost identical in all major browsers. I guess it's a stylistic choice then, whichever seems most readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modular division operator '%' can be used to get the *remainder* of a division in JS. This means that if we perform the modular division of a floating point number by 1, we get the value after the decimal point. Further, if we build a loop where we multiply by 10 until there is no longer anything after the decimal point, we can find the smallest power of ten we can multiply the original number by to get an integer.

Example below:

```
function getE(floatingPointValue)
{
    var x = floatingPointValue;
    var digitsAfterDecimal = 0;
    while(x % 1 != 0)
    {
        x = x * 10;
        digitsAfterDecimal++;
    }
    return x.toString() + " *10^-" + digitsAfterDecimal;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8XtP/2/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, and talking about metric prefixes, similar method with division may be used. Thanks!